# Tracetel RFID device shows as unclaimed

Tags: drivers, usb

I wanted to connect a Tracetel RFID device to my laptop via USB but when I do so it does absolutely not function at all.
Output of `lshw`

```
*-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:24 memory:f1500000-f150ffff
       *-usbhost:0
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 3.19.0-22-generic xhci-hcd
            physical id: 0
            bus info: usb@2
            logical name: usb2
            version: 3.19
            capabilities: usb-3.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
       *-usbhost:1
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 3.19.0-22-generic xhci-hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@1
            logical name: usb1
            version: 3.19
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb:0 UNCLAIMED
               description: Generic USB device
               product: TRACETEL RFID
               vendor: TI
               physical id: 2
               bus info: usb@1:2
               version: 1.00
               serial: 3210
               capabilities: usb-1.10
               configuration: maxpower=200mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

so basically as far as I understand, that means that there is no driver that is claiming this device right?

The question is what exactly can I do about it?

Support by Tracetel themselves is rather poor.

Comment: Hello Rick, did you find any solution for this issue?